# How to manage https for CNames of different domains on my domain (different one)

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, http, https, subdomain

I have a situation where I have an SSL certificate for my domain, for example, "example.com". My clients use subdomains (CName) to point to my domain "example.com". I have permanent redirection on example.com which will keep any request on https.

When customers try to access content from my domain using their CName which is pointing to example.com with https, it doesn't work as there is no https configured for their subdomain on my domain or on my Apache configuration. I have little knowledge about the whole DNS thing but I am learning.

If I want to achieve the functionality where I can manage these subdomains to be on https, How can I do that? By the way... there are hundreds of customers using their subdomains to point to example.com

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using "catch-all" VirtualHosts for the HTTP(s) layer and having your customers provide you certificates and keys for whatever domain they're using.

Comment: Is there a way I can use a third party tool like letsencrypt.org or any other tool to obtain certificates for these custom domains and install it on my web server? I am just trying to understand if there is any way i can avoid involving the customers?

Answer (score 0):

If the purpose of these `CNAME` records is that they are easier to remember, for example `webmail` subdomains for the company domain instead of `webmail-provider.example.com`, you don't necessarily need to have HTTPS configured for them at all.

Just add a catch-all plain HTTP virtualhost that performs an *HTTP redirect* to your original domain on HTTPS. It could be served via HTTPS too, but that way you don't need to require your customers to pay / send you certificates for their subdomains, if this service is not designed to be their own web site actually needing TLS.